# Windows 8 isn't detecting PS3 eye

Tags: windows-8, drivers, camera, ps3, hardware-detection

I have the PS3 Eye web cam installed with drivers from Code Laboratories, which comes with a test program.

When I open the test program it shows a clear picture from the webcam. Every other program does not detect a webcam. The cam shows in my device manager and as installed correctly.

My question is, is there a flag or something like that I can set that will show Windows 8 that this device is in fact a camera and is working.

Here is a picture of the test program that comes loaded with the drivers and the windows 8 camera app.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, as are some others: http://codelaboratories.com/forums/viewthread/984/ I just sent a message to the developers, but we'll see if they add in Windows 8 support anytime soon.

Comment: Try clicking the *Devices* tab, then PS3-EYE-CAM – or whatever it's called.

Answer (score 3):

Code Laboratories CL Eye driver exposes a DirectShow interface and is therefore compatible with desktop apps that also implement Directshow. However, Windows Store apps use the newer MediaFoundation API and hence are not compatible with the CL driver. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8f045f59-b03f-4328-a13c-bd90bf9545b1/directshow-and-windows-8

Comment: This was helpful for me. I removed the Skype App from the windows Store and installed the normal Desktop Application from the Skype website. Now CL Eye is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If windows 8 has the ability... try running the driver installer in compatibility mode for windows xp (or whatever windows version it's compatible with) and as admin

Answer (score 0):

Dump CL-eye driver for open source one.

https://github.com/inspirit/PS3EYEDriver